# Preserving an ArrayAdapter that is set to a ListView on change of orientation

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

```
Android Studio 0.4.4
```

Hello,

================ Update:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            friendsList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(ADAPTER_KEY);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, friendsList);
            lvFriends.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList(ADAPTER_KEY, friendsList);
    }
```

I have ListView that is filled with data that I want to preserve when the user changes the orientation.

I add items to an ArrayList:

```
arraylist.add(friend);
```

I then I create my Array Adapter:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraylist);
lvFriends.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When the user changes orientation I lose all my data in the ListView (lvFriends).

I have experimented with onSaveInstanceState, but the following just crashed.

```
private final String ADAPTER_KEY = "ADAPTER_KEY";
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        adapter = (ArrayAdapter)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(ADAPTER_KEY);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(ADAPTER_KEY, (Serializable)adapter);
}
```

My SDK that I am support is from `API 10 to API 19`.
`public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` is deprecated in API level 13.

I am not looking to save anything to a sqlite database, as that is overkill for such a simple app.

Just looking for simple way to solve this problem.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: `onRetain...` is deprecated but you have the option of a retained fragment. Is building the list backing the adapter so expensive that you can't do it again after the configuration change? And an adapter can't be put in a `Bundle`(and you wouldn't want to do that anyway)

Comment: So basically I will be saving the ArrayList in the onSaveInstanceState. Then onCreate I will retrieve it and pass it to the adapter when I create a new one, and then bind it to the ListView? Thanks.

Comment: @Luksprog, I have updated my question with your latest idea. But it crashed on the lvFriends.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Can you also post the exception you get?

Comment: It was just a programming error on my part. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parcelable object solved my problem.

I anyone else is interested I can post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put this thing in activity tag in Menifest file:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: That is not possible, as the app needs to function when it is in portrait mode and landscape mode. All the layout have already been designed. So I can't possibly change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add this line on Menifest.xml file.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```